# get var in blade from included blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

I trying to set a php variable in blade. Its works but also on the same blade and not set the var on the other blades.

example:

header.blade.php

```
@if(isset($company))
   @php ($color = $company->color)
@else
   @php ($color = $app_color)
@endif
The color: {{$color}}  //Output: The color: green
```

and if I included that blade to another blade its not set this var.
like:

index.blade.php

```
@include('header')
The Color: {{$color}}
//Output: The Color: green
//The Color: null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

header.blade.php

```
@if(isset($company))
   @php $color = $company->color; @endphp
@else
   @php $color = $app_color; @endphp
@endif
```

index.blade.php

```
@include('header')
The Color: {{ $color}}
```

Comment: `echo` shouldn't be there as `{{}}` already takes care of output

Answer (score 0):

Because $color is the local variable. It is same as if you declare $color variable in A function and it's scope is within the function. If you can access $color in B function of the same class it's not accessible. Your above situation same like this.

You can put this code in your controller:

```
if(isset($company)) {
    $color = $company->color;
} else {
    $color = $app_color;
}
return view('index', compact('color', $color));
```

And Now you can access **$color** variable in both **index** and **header** view if you include this line **@include('header')** in index blade view.
I hope this will be helpful.